# closing tab after submiting form

Tags: javascript, php

I have researched as much as I can about this issue, and have so far not found a solution that works.

Essentially what I have is a PHP page where the user enters match results, the form action includes a header that takes them to the updated league table. I have disabled caching from the page where the user enters results, but this does not accommodate for the 'back' button being clicked in the browser. If they do click back, the page shows it's previous state, before the last scores they entered, which, if submitted, causes a real problem with the league tables.

At the minute I have got the form action to run in a new tab, meaning they cannot click 'back' in the browser, and instead must use a 'back' link, which means the page will always be re-rendered. Great, but the issue is that the form page is stil open in it's original tab.

Is there a way around this. I realise that calling a javascript closeWindow() function 'onSubmit' will close the window before the database is updated.

This is what I have so far, the new tab opens, but the original one remains open.
For added info, the page that I need to close, is opened in a new tab itself from a link on the homepage.

```
<?php

require_once "pdo_enl_connect.php";
$database=dbNB_connect();

echo "<table>";
echo "<form action=\"update_table_a.php\" target=\"_blank\" method=\"post\">";
$query=$database->query("SELECT team_id, team_name, team_score, opposition_score,     opposition_id, opposition_name from results_a");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"team[]\" value=\"$row[1]\">
     <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"opposition[]\" value=\"$row[5]\">
     <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"team_id[]\" value=\"$row[0]\">
     <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"opposition_id[]\" value=\"$row[4]\">
    <tr><td>$row[1]<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"team_score[]\" value=\"$row[2]\"     <td>
     <input type=\"text\" name=\"opposition_score[]\" value=\"$row[3]\"><td>$row[5]    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$query2=$database->query("SELECT team_score, opposition_score from results_a");

while ($row = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {

echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prev_team_score[]\" value=\"$row[0]\">
      <td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prev_o_score[]\" value=\"$row[1]\">";
}


echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\" name=\"go\">";

echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: after update unset variables ....

Comment: sorry, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    


    if(isset($_POST['buttonname']))
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";

?>
```

and Remove the `window.close()` from the `onSubmit`

Comment: I tried this, but it just closes the window as it opens. I placed it at the end of the php script on the form page, is this the correct location?

Comment: hmmm still no luck, I tried this before too as had seen it posted elsewhere on this site. The new tab opens, but this one still remains open

Comment: add a code snippet in your question then,  ill have a look at it after lunch then

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using AJAX for the onSubmit?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST","submitdata.php",false);
request.onload = function(){ window.close(); };
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&pass="+pass...);
```

This will send the form data to a php script that updates the data, then after the response loads, it will close the window. This is synchronous ("false" in the request opening), so users shouldn't be able to mess your database up.